# facebook login using url # prepends access token php

Tags: php, facebook, url, redirect

yeah so I have a button that let users login to my app via facebook using redirect url

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
                            client_id=xxxxxxx&
                            redirect_uri=<?php echo base_url() ?>user/fblogin&
                            response_type=code%20token">
                                Login with facebook
</a>
```

In the url facebook replies with (notice the #)

```
http://my-site.co.jp/user/fblogin?#access_token=CAAL520EmBRIBAJjslRmPMabcdefg8ZCHtiLExYwQf4HS2FhRsIOH7qMmntDnvzqQ20FKTiBscoP9gP2VZCX3snAhLkJYchkQNrWZCZBk5BZBNNwVSby9T0jY20aQhGVI90tmGsnrohCAYvZBGMT7TkNS6YH0hkeVpITqlPhXcAfjGipHHeEQhPIpI8M8fJYbbZBbeKBJt1kAfybJQd2HLxQ2yC&expires_in=5182917&code=AQCLGq5Sr98OdowT6kly_jvekac0z1sd3-_P_9aNcNbp4AjlYyWX3AQPfiGMODtmziNY8YMSXCCYySrH1pvhlUUL8btcOYvQJRcW-qNHCMvDc21gRSL9Zw0yE3ZxZGHQxXJeeDXnh8sqEh2UqwjzrUpgnC9Qb9xz2hQxKpalVn5-tQTZ8wFmHbTjg9gL0rOK504JHCCWExaOAAQwASvKUSrNlfPxHv0XGjarebadsfkf538TCqCTbFIkLMIK52DvXljQ5ODWUJqzxiphrIUCLhZYnZcdW6jratH-rLqwxDwxs6CIwkVWVBwDpyu1jeQjbxAYtjdo2pnDRHuVJlFePzDFiD
```

now I can't get the access token's value via $_REQUEST or $_GET because of the #...

I want to get the accesstoken's value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the official [facebook-php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

That's by design I think. Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login

which states

> `code%20token` Response data is included as a URL fragment and contains both an access token and the code parameter.

Why they don't pass both keys as parameters is not clear to me, but you should be able to do some string operations in PHP easily to split the URL etc...

Have a look at http://codepad.org/Qktxh475

```
<?
$url = "http://my-site.co.jp/user/fblogin?#access_token=CAAL520EmBRIBAJjslRmPMabcdefg8ZCHtiLExYwQf4HS2FhRsIOH7qMmntDnvzqQ20FKTiBscoP9gP2VZCX3snAhLkJYchkQNrWZCZBk5BZBNNwVSby9T0jY20aQhGVI90tmGsnrohCAYvZBGMT7TkNS6YH0hkeVpITqlPhXcAfjGipHHeEQhPIpI8M8fJYbbZBbeKBJt1kAfybJQd2HLxQ2yC&expires_in=5182917&code=AQCLGq5Sr98OdowT6kly_jvekac0z1sd3-_P_9aNcNbp4AjlYyWX3AQPfiGMODtmziNY8YMSXCCYySrH1pvhlUUL8btcOYvQJRcW-qNHCMvDc21gRSL9Zw0yE3ZxZGHQxXJeeDXnh8sqEh2UqwjzrUpgnC9Qb9xz2hQxKpalVn5-tQTZ8wFmHbTjg9gL0rOK504JHCCWExaOAAQwASvKUSrNlfPxHv0XGjarebadsfkf538TCqCTbFIkLMIK52DvXljQ5ODWUJqzxiphrIUCLhZYnZcdW6jratH-rLqwxDwxs6CIwkVWVBwDpyu1jeQjbxAYtjdo2pnDRHuVJlFePzDFiD";

$parameters = substr($url, strpos($url, "#") + 1);
$parameter_array = explode("&", $parameters);

echo "Access Token: " . substr($parameter_array[0], strpos($parameter_array[0], "=") + 1) . "\n";
echo "Expires: " . substr($parameter_array[1], strpos($parameter_array[1], "=") + 1) . "\n";
echo "Code: " . substr($parameter_array[2], strpos($parameter_array[2], "=") + 1) . "\n";
?>
```